# Multiple problems formatting dropdown menu in CSS

Tags: html, css

Multiple questions regarding styling a dropdown menu made using HTML and CSS:

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZWaV.jpg) is a screenshot of what the menu currently looks like.

Related HTML code:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  /*padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px; these do nothing*/
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}
ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
li ul {
  display: none;
}
ul li a {
  /*display: inline;*/
  background: #636363;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
ul li a:hover {
  background: #383838;
}
li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
li:hover li {
  float: none;
}
/*li:hover a {
 background: #636363;
 } this does nothing!*/

li:hover li a:hover {
  background: #383838;
}
#drop-nav li ul li {
  border-top: 5px;
  /*this does nothing!!*/
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul id="drop-nav">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="best.html">Best</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="process.html">Process</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="upcoming.html">Upcoming</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="winter.html">Winter 2014</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="spring.html">Spring 2015</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="summer.html">Summer 2015</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="fall.html">Fall 2015</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

As you can see, there are a few problems. First, submenus are appearing to the right of their parent menus. I've tried changing the position property of everything relating to the menu, and nothing seems to work. Setting li:hover ul to relative causes some VERY buggy things to start happening; the menu appears in still the wrong place and jumps around the screen rapidly.

Second, submenus are overlapping one another. I've tried changing height and display properties to no avail.

Third, the submenus become hidden under the image gallery. I have no idea why. Here is all code related to the image gallery:

```css
.aslider {
  margin: auto;
  width: 550px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="a-slider/aslider.js"></script>
</head>

<!--skip irrelevant code-->

<div class="aslider" data-hide-controls>
  <div class="aslide" data-duration="5">
    <img src="images/pic1.jpg" width="550px" height="300px">
    <!--placeholder-->
  </div>
  <div class="aslide" data-duration="5">
    <img src="images/pic2.jpg" width="550px" height="300px">
    <!--placeholder-->
  </div>
</div>
```

This problem began when I changed the display property of .aslider to inline-block, which I needed to do in order to have it centered properly. The problem is probably somewhere around there, but I've tried changing a few things and haven't found any solutions.

Fourth, I need to set the width of all nav menus and submenus to be equal. Yes, I am a perfectionist and this is annoying me :( I've tried adding a width property to different parts of the css but can't find anything that works. I'm not sure where to add the width property, or even if I should be using it.

Wew, ok. That's all for now. I will have the babies of anyone who can help me. I've been playing around trying to figure these out for days now and haven't gone anywhere!

Sorry for the superlong post.

//EDIT
Here is the entire css for the page:

```css
html {
  background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  color: #2ae926;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#banner {
  text-align: center;
}
#currentpage {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
a {
  color: #2ae926;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav {
  height: 60px;
  font-family: source code pro black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  background-color: #636363;
  width: 70%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
nav a {
  border-style: outset;
  border-color: #424242;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #2ae926;
}
nav a:hover {
  border-style: inset;
}
nav li {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
#b1 {
  background-color: #636363;
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 500px;
}
h1 {
  font-family: source code pro black;
  font-size: 35px;
}
#b2text {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.aslider {
  margin: auto;
  width: 550px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  top: 15px;
}
/*#gumi {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 7.5%;
 margin-top: 10%;
 }*/

/* this puts the image where it needs to go but
        moves everything else to the right. fix!! */

footer {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: #636363;
  width: 70%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
footer a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline
}
pre {
  padding-top: 3px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  /*padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px; these do nothing*/
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}
ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
li ul {
  display: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
  width: auto;
}
ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #636363;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 110px;
}
ul li a:hover {
  background: #383838;
}
li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  /*absolute*/
}
li:hover li {
  float: none;
}
/*li:hover a {
 background: #636363;
 }*/

li:hover li a:hover {
  background: #383838;
}
#drop-nav li ul li {
  border-top: 5px;
  /*this does nothing!!*/
}
```

Comment: Can you add a fiddle showing your problem?

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. What is a fiddle? I've added a screenshot showing the things that are going wrong, is that enough?

Comment: Add li ul {
    padding-left: 0;
} to prevent your menu being too far left.

Comment: li ul { padding-left: 0; } has no effect

Comment: A fiddle is a site where you copy all your code. It's very easy to use and you can include frameworks like jquery and bootstrap. It is used to show others what problems you are encountering, as having some 'live' code to debug is far easier then figuring out what is wrong from just reading the code. I tried to visualize your problem here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/d2brbL2x/1/

Comment: That is pretty much exactly what's happening, but the submenus appear to the right as mentioned

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/d2brbL2x/2/ They appear fine for me there, maybe it is a browser related problem? What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using the latest version of Chrome. The second link you posted is different to the first, it it working ok, but the width of the submenus is still different. Apart from that, it's good.

Comment: If you want all your submenus to be the same width, you need to give them all the width of your largest one. I'll edit my fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/d2brbL2x/5/

Add

```
li ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    width: auto;
}
```

to your code.
This is needed as 'ul's have a standard padding left value, which caused your submenus to appear to the right of their parent.

Edit: the width: auto is needed as you gave your uls a width of 500px, but I assume you don't want this for your submenus.

```
ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px;
}
```

Use this to make all your submenus the same size. You will need to adjust the value of width according to your font etc.

Please take a look at the fiddle and tell me if that is what you were looking for.

Edit: here is the adjusted code:

```
   ul {
       width: 100%;
   }

   ul li a {
       width: 150px;
   }


   li ul {
       padding-left: 0;
       width: auto;
   }

   ul li ul li {
       padding-left: 0;
       padding-right: 0;
   }

   ul li ul li a {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 200px;
   }
```

Comment: Your change to li ul works in the fiddle, but is not working on the actual document. There is more than likely something else in the css interfering. Would you like me to post the entire page of css? Your change to ul li a works alright, so thank you for that one :)

Comment: Sure, post your page and we can try to figure out what exactly is interfering with your css.

Comment: Added the full css to my question. Sorry for poor formatting!

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/d2brbL2x/7/. Does that code work on your page? If not, your problem must be related to a file you include, like a js file or something. I added the lines I added to my answer.

Comment: I'm getting excited. This works great, minus one thing - nav{text-align: center;} is being ignored for some reason. The links are all sticking to the left of the nav bar.

Comment: Your 'li's have float: left, this overwrites any text-align. I'll look into it for you.

Comment: removing float: left and changing display to inline-block gets the nav links pretty close to the center, but a tad to the right. I can't find what's causing this

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/d2brbL2x/8/ Your ul has a padding-left, this gets automatically added, use ul {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 0;
} to remove it. Check my fiddle.

Comment: Bingo. I love you. The nav is now working exactly how I want it. You've done enough already, but if you want to help even more, there is still the problem of nav submenus being hidden under the slider gallery. I feel it'll be a bit of a pain to work on in a fiddle so if you want to help, I can send you a zip folder containing stuff youll need?

Comment: Let's use the chat feature as these comments are getting fairly long: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74621/multiple-problems-formatting-dropdown-menu-in-css

Comment: Apparently you need 20 rep to do that, of which I have 10. Hooray.

Comment: Oh wow, sorry I didn't realize that. It's actually a bit silly. Anyways, sure send me your files, I'll take a look through them.

Comment: Ahh... is there any way to pm you etc? If you have google drive I can share the zip folder with you, but youll need to give me your email

Comment: There is no way for a private message here, but if you post the drive link without the sharing options enabled, I should be able to request access for it with my google account. You should get an email about it and from there I think you can grant me the access. I just don't really want to post my google mail address here.

Comment: This should be the share link <removed>

Didn't know how to get a link without sharing options enabled so whatever :)

Comment: Worked fine. You can remove the link now if you don't want others to download it.

Comment: Are we able to get an instant messenger going? Pretty sure google does have one but I don't know how to start it with someone not on my contacts

Comment: I couldn't find a way to add you, but ive started a hangouts conversation with you, which sounds like itll do. It says you dont currently have hangouts though, so im not sure how that works

Answer (score 0):

1. add `top` and `left` positioning for `li:hover ul`
2. add `margin-top` to `#drop-nav li ul li`
3. I don't see such a problem in my fiddle
4. add `width` to `ul li`

note- you haven't put all the css in here so you should add appropriate property values according to your needs. that's why i haven't mentioned any specific values in above answers.

check my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p9428eqv/3/)

Comment: 1. This brings the submenus closer to where they should be, but they're still to the right.

2. This did nothing

3. That's strange. Nothing should be different as far as I'm aware

4. This did nothing

Comment: 1. you mean not perfectly aligned to the left like your image?
2, 3. did you check my fiddle? may be some other script or css conflicting with the stuff you post above. It's difficult to tell because in the fiddle I cannot see any issue.

Comment: 3. for this matter I'm suggesting that conflicting is causing by `aslider.js`